# Decrease text indentation to level N after headline at level N+1

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am using org-mode to write papers and I am often confronted the following problem: starting from

```
* A
** A1
   Text for level A1
** A2
   Text for level A2
```

I want to add an additional information after `Text for level A2` but at the level of A as follows:

```
* A
** A1
   Text for level A1
** A2
   Text for level A2
  Text stil in section A but not in section A2
```

But org mode does not seem to enable this and aligns the text with section A2.

I tried to insert an "artificial" section

```
* 
  Text stil in section A but not in section A2
```

but it appears in the LaTeX export and therefore this is not a satisfactory solution. Is there a way to solve this problem, for instance by adjusting the export of the "artificial" section to make it invisible in the exported document ?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible at all.  You can't "raise" the level of a text after a subsection.  How would that even look like in a document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Org-mode FAQ](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#closing-outline-sections):

> The short answer to the question is no. Org-mode adheres to the cascading logic of outlines, in which a section is closed only by another section that occupies an equal or greater level.

The FAQ suggests a few workarounds that may or may not work for you.

There is also [ignore headings](https://github.com/noorul/org-mode/blob/master/contrib/lisp/ox-extra.el) to use in your exports, which would ignore a tagged headline but would cause its children to be promoted by one, so I'm not entirely sure if it's worth it.